# Returning docx file from scala server

Tags: scala, apache-poi, docx

I am using a scala akka-http server. I created a `docx (word)` file on the server side and I want to return a response such that when the response reaches the client, an auto-download process should start. I am using angular2 on the client side. Also, for creating the docx file POI is used.

```
val document = new XWPFDocument //create an empty Document
val paragraph = document.createParagraph()
val titleRun = paragraph.createRun()
//Some configuration..
....
document.write(new FileOutputStream(new File("./" + title.trim() + ".docx")))
```

Here is a method triggered by the user request. For now the file is saved to the current directory. So the question is, how can I change my code to make the file sent through the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

akka-http has directives for serving files to client requests

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/file-and-resource-directives/getFromFile.html

You might be able to able to use a PipedOutputStream instead of a FileOuputStream - eg https://github.com/pjfanning/prometheus-akka-sample/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/example/akka/http/PrometheusService.scala